# Installing HP printer/scanner driver fails

Tags: windows-7, drivers, scanner, hp-laserjet

Objective: Get scanning to work with a Hewlett Packard MFP M276nw, connected via USB to a Windows 7 x64 system.

What I did, step by step:

1. Uninstall printer driver from Device Manager.
2. Uninstall HP software from `Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features`.
3. Manually run HP driver uninstaller:

   ```
   C:\Users\Felix\AppData\Local\Temp\7zS5163\Uninstall.exe
   ```
4. Unplug the device from USB.
5. As Administrator, start the latest printer/scanner setup tool, downloaded from the HP web site: `HP LaserJet Pro 200 Color M276 PCL6 Print Scan Driver with Installer - LJ-Pro-200-color-MFP-M276-driver-installer-15188.exe`
6. Plug in USB when asked by the setup tool. Now, something possibly goes wrong already: Windows 7 picks up driver installation in parallel.

   [image: Screenshot showing setup tool and Windows' driver installer]
7. Wait until the setup tool finishes, unfortunately with an error message: "An install operation took too long to execute. This is a fatal error preventing product use. Please restart your computer, and run this installer again. If the problem persists, please check the product support web site for your product."

   [image: Screenshot showing setup tool with error message]

The [log file of the HP setup tool](https://gist.github.com/feklee/4bef1278bf41e232d3d4) shows details about the error message, but I don't know what to look for. The Windows driver installation log file `C:\Windows\inf\setupapi.dev.log` looks fine, no error messages.

*What can I try to solve the problem?*

See also [my post](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Scanning-Faxing-and-Copying/Installing-HP-printer-scanner-driver-fails-and-now/td-p/5429803) in the HP support forums.

Comment: Some [HP printer tools here](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02073861)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just followed the procedure again, but with an additional step *1a:* Uninstall printer from `Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers`

Prior to that, I ran the [HP Print and Scan Doctor](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02073861), but that only showed which devices are installed. I doubt that it *fixed* anything.

Anyhow, this time installation worked, although again I had to wait a long time for the setup tool to finish. Possibly it's a timing issue.

No TWAIN interface seems to have been installed for the MFP. Possibly that requires the full setup with the HP scan software. However, I can now scan with VueScan, which did not work before.

Comment: I'd suggest using NAPS 2 for your scanning, but that's just an idea. If your software works then everything's fine I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Go into the printers settings (*in the printer itself*) and **turn off "HP Smart Install"**.

**Settings** -> **Service** -> **HP Smart Install** -> **Off**

Then try to install it again, and it should work.

I've been fixing this at work a few times now.

Answer (score 1):

- This happens most time when I Install HP's printers, it stucks at 99%
  at some time and then it shows error...
- I fix this by manually install printer driver from Device Manager.
- First you need to extract printer driver and copy that location where
  you extract it.
- Go to Device Manager/Printers, right click Update Driver, then click
  Browse, locate extracted driver (You can pasle already copied link)
  and install it manually.

Comment: Very much THIS!

Thanks Sir, unbelievable how unintelligent (and unhelpful) this "*Smart* Install" is.... WTF...